# A div before a centered div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with a lot of headlines. If someone clicks on the headline, a button before (e.g. 10px) the headline (left hand side) should be displayed.

The problem is the headlines should always be centered - if the button is displayed or not. The headlines should not change their positions if the button is displayed / hidden.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .headline {
        background-color: grey;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 70%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="headline">Headline 1</div>
    <div class="headline">Headline 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ct11gp3v/

I have tried a lot with position absolute.. but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is not so clear what are you asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick the button inside of the headline, and make it position absolute:

```css
.headline {
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative; /* This will allow the button to be
                           displayed relative to the headline */
}

.headline div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">Headline 1 <div>Test</div></div>
<div class="headline">Headline 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. could you use <div> instead of <button>? (my bad)

Comment: @NoobieNoob Sure, it can be any element. (In my example I changed it to a plain div, but you should give it a class, to be able to identify it as a button.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. In this case you need to know the width of the button.

```css
  .headline {
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .headline button{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -120px;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .headline:hover button{
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
 

<div class="headline"><button>A button</button>Headline 1</div>
<div class="headline"><button>A button</button>Headline 2</div>
```

And please do not write non-semantic code. Use h1-h7 for headlines rather than class-names.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. could you use <div> instead of <button>? (my bad)

Answer (score -1):

Give the button position : absolute

```
button {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcdoweljn/Lcatswy5/)

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Short code doesn't mean incorrect code. If you downvote, please say why